# Only met by a tty "login" prompt when booting Mint

Tags: linux, linux-mint, login, tty

I've installed Linux Mint 11 Katya (dual-booting with Win7) on my PC. After some problems with booting, I  decided to use NeoGrub to add a Grub-based bootloader, configurable from within Windows, to the standard Windows boot manager. Fine.
However, when I boot Mint from there, I don't get any GUI. I only get a tty prompt, saying

> Linux Mint Katya kapok login:

Kapok is my hostname. This shouldn't show up, right? And what am I supposed to type in there, really? The password I chose during installation? The username? Both? Whatever I type seems to return a message like this

> tty1 Main Process (*a number*) killed by SEGV signal

Followed by the same login prompt as before.
If I switch tty with Alt+Ctrl+F? I get the same prompt, except on F7 (which should be the GUI?) where it only shows some kind of log text but no prompt.

Is there actually some problem here, or is it just me who's stupid and don't get what to do? (never used Linux before)

Also, here's the Grub code I use to boot Mint:

```
title Linux Mint 11 Katya
find --set-root /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic
kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-generic ro root=/dev/sda5
initrd /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-8-generic
```

Comment: There's a problem, and something is broken or not properly configured (I don't know what, but the behaviour you're getting is not normal).

Comment: I've done some Googling, but everything related to only console showing seems to include typing commands. But I can't type commands, it just wants me to login. What's the proper syntax for logging in from the console?

Comment: You type in your username at the `login:` prompt; press Enter. You should then get a `Password:` prompt, where you should type in your password and press Enter again.

Comment: @JennyD That's what I thought, but it didn't work. Only got that error message...

Comment: Sorry, I skimmed the post too quickly. Something's very broken indeed since the tty doesn't work at all. I'm guessing you don't get any network interfaces working either?

Comment: @JennyD What do you mean by "network interface?

Comment: I think your system is broken, reinstall it. Sorry if i ask... why Mint 11?? Now there is Mint 16....

Comment: @maurelio79 Mint 11? Long story, it's an old install. But yes, maybe it's best to burn a fresh Mint 16 cd and reinstall. What do you suggest doing with the old Mint partition and OS? Delete it before installing or overwriting it with the fresh install?

Comment: When you start the installation, you format partitions with mint 11, recreate partitions and install mint 16.